# Сделать карту размером 100% от "оставшегося"

Tags: javascript, html, css

Всем привет, вот планк http://plnkr.co/edit/binMUB7iI8duv6sJTrJC?p=preview
На нем есть карта , используется leaflet.js. 
Задача: сделать адаптивный layout для страницы.

Я выбрал решение на таблицах, так как там можно сделать элемент высотой 100% от оставшейся. Но возникла проблема с картой: почему-то она расширяет ячейку до непонятных размеров, и футер с текстом после карты пропадают на задний план. Если не поможете, то хотя бы объясните, почему такое поведение?

Код:

```css
  html,body{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
    * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
    .wide {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }
    
    .auto {
      height: auto;
    }
    
    .table {
      display: table;
    }
    
    .table__row {
      display: table-row;
    }
    
    .table__cell {
      display: table-cell;
      vertical-align: top;
    }
    /*ВАЖНО ИМЕННО 100%*/
  #map {
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
    }
```

```html
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet/v0.7.7/leaflet.css" />
  <script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet/v0.7.7/leaflet.js"></script>  
<div style="border: 1px solid red; width:100%; height:100%; display: table">
    <div style="width:100%; height:100px;border: 1px solid green; display:table-row">
      <h1>HEADER</h1>
    </div>
    <div style="width:14%; height:100%;border: 1px solid blue; display:table-cell;">
      SIDEBAR
    </div>
    <div style="width:84%; height:100%; border: 1px solid gray; display:table-cell; ">
      <div class="table wide">
        <div class="table__row">
          <div class="table_cell" style="height: 100%;">
            <div style="width:100%; height:100%;border: 1px dotted red; ">
              <h1 class="auto">Заголовок</h1>
              <div id="map"></div>
              <p class="auto">Какой то текст Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis, quibusdam, pariatur, doloribus quisquam dolores eius veritatis blanditiis totam odio error sapiente dicta doloremque alias voluptates laudantium molestias officia laboriosam iusto.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="table__row">
          <div class="table__cell" style="width:100%; height:100px;border: 1px solid green;">
            <h1>FOOTER</h1>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script>
    var map = L.map('map').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);
     L.marker([51.5, -0.09]).addTo(map);
  </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Всё просто - вы сами себя обманули утверждением "100% от оставшегося".
У таблиц ячейки распределяют между собой свободное пространство в зависимости:

1. от указанных размеров

Если какой-то размер не указан - распределяется оставшееся свободное пространство.

2. от размеров содержимого